# ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH - Android Webview

Tags: android, android-webview, tls1.2, tls1.3

I have a simple andriod application , which has only one activity to load a webpage using a webview.While building the app I am using minimum sdk version as 24, which means the app should work on android 7 and above, but due to some reason when i launch my application in android 7.1 , I am getting ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH error as below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOK7q.png)

surprisingly when i browse the same url directly in browser it does work. Please help me to resolve this issue.

current chrome version:- 90.0.4430.60
Android version:- 7.1

I have tried updating the chrome version in the device and if i update to chrome version 110+ then it starts working, but i wanted to check if this is the right way to fix the issue or do we have any better solution.

[image]

The server from which it is loading the webpage is using **TLS** v 1.3, somewhere i read by default android 7 uses TLS 1.2 , and this issue can come due to different tls version, so please help me if we can handle this issue without updating the browser version for android 7.

My WebView config

`````
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        webView = findViewById(R.id.test);
        ProgressBar spinner = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        settings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient(spinner));
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new CustomWebChromeClient(this,webChromeClientArgs));
        webView.loadUrl("https://www.test.com/");
    ````
`````

Comment: Thanks @Robert, Does that mean we have only option to update the chrome/webview to make it work in android 7 ?

Comment: You have to update the "app" that is providing WebViews to other apps. In Android 7 AFAIR Google used Chrome for doing so, so yes, updating Chrome is from my perspective essential.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default TLS 1.3 is only enabled on [Android 10+](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/behavior-changes-all#tls-1.3) however that applies to apps using the Java API.

But Web browsers like Chrome and the Android WebView have their own TLS implementation, so they can have TLS 1.3 enabled by default on older Android versions. So make sure [Chrome](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.android.chrome&hl=en) respectively [Android System WebView](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.webview&hl=en) are up-to-date.

You can check if Chrome or "Android System WebView" is used to provide WebView to apps in Android Developer options entry "WebView implementation".

At least your mentioned Chrome version is old and outdated. Chrome version 90 was released more than 2 years ago. Now (Nov 2023), latest Chrome version is 118.

Comment: I was just wondering how does the web app loads fine if i browse the url directly from chrome browser, but the same fails if loading through the webview

Comment: @abhishek Then most likely the webview is provided by "Android System WebView" on your device, or you have applied a different configuration of the WebView or use the WebView in an unusual way (e.g. implement a custom connection in `shouldInterceptRequest`).

Comment: @abhishek Please don't post code in comments. Edit your question instead.

Comment: Sure, I have updated the question

Comment: I guess i got what you are saying , I just saw , though my chrome is 90.0.4430.66, webview is even older which 55.2.2883.91, and if i am updating my chrome version to 110, then webview is also getting updated along with the browser, then app starts working, just curious to know is there a way where i can specify to use browser instead of webview while setting up my android webview config?

Comment: @abhishek Where you can specify the WebView implementation provider is already included in my answer.

Comment: My application has only webview with single activity, basically this android app is acting as a shell app for the webapp, which i am loading inside webview.

Comment: Got you, looks like this we can check/specify from developer option , Initially i thought i could do it from the code. Please correct me if my understanding is wrong, as i am beginner in android app development.

Comment: @abhishek Apps can not change system settings like the WebView implementation to be used. You may be able to detect which implementation is used but changing is not possible. BTW if may answer was helpful feel free to upvote and/or accept it.